# MIQP formulation in L0 norm optimization

Tags: integer-programming, binary-quadratic-forms

Consider the L0 norm compressed sensing problem:

$$\eqalign{
  & \min \quad {x^T}Qx + {c^T}x + {\mu\left\| x \right\|_0}  \cr 
  & s.t:\quad Ax \le b \cr} $$

Suppose I do want to solve this problem as is (or use the best possible heuristics available) using state of the art software like Gurobi instead of doing L1 norm approximation. How should I reformulate the problem to achieve best results practically? I know that I could perform do the big M formulation though in MIQP, is it the best we could do in terms of practice (I could tolerate inexact/"almost optimally practically" solutions)?

Comment: Perhaps the paper by Bertsimas et al. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03133.pdf) is a relevant reference.

Comment: Are all the decision variables integral?

Comment: Maybe this is relevant as well - https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.05937.